# Given a list of lists, build a list in which lists with equal first and last elements are grouped together

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists, and I'd like to build a new list, in which lists are in the same list if they have the same first and last element. Here's an example. Suppose I have

```
{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

After some magic has happened, I would like to have

```
{ {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}, {{2, 4, 5}}, {{3, 4, 5}} }
```

I was looking at `Select` and the others, but I can only come with ugly explicit loops that achieve this. I'm sure there's a nicer way of doing this. What could that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following shall group the lists notwithstanding their order:

```
list = {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}};
GatherBy[list, {First@#, Last@#} &]

(*
{{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 4}}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}}, {{2, 4, 5}}, {{3, 4, 5}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list={{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}};

SplitBy[list, #[[{1, -1}]] &]
(* {{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}, {{2, 4, 5}}, {{3, 4, 5}}} *)
```

Comment: I think it isn't grouping the lists if they aren't contiguous

Comment: Shouldn't that be `GatherBy`?

Comment: For some reason I interpreted the question as contiguous

Comment: Okay, fair enough. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
 list = {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}};
 gthr[l_] :=  Cases[l, #] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[{#[[1]], ___, #[[-1]]} & /@ l] 
 gthr[list]
 (* { {{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{1,3,4,4}}, {{1,2,4,5}}, {{2,4,5}}, {{3,4,5}}} *)
```

**Update:** `gthr` decoded:

Form patterns from the first and last members of sublists in `list`:

```
 {#[[1]], ___, #[[-1]]}& /@ list   
 (* {{1, ___, 4}, {1, ___, 4}, {1, ___, 5}, {1, ___, 4}, {2, ___, 5}, {3, ___, 5}}*)
```

Remove duplicate elements from the list of patterns:

```
 DeleteDuplicates[%] 
 (* {{1, ___, 4}, {1, ___, 5}, {2, ___, 5}, {3, ___, 5}} *)
```

For each pattern get the elements in `list` matching that pattern:

```
 Cases[list,#]&/@%  
 (* { {{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{1,3,4,4}}, {{1,2,4,5}}, {{2,4,5}}, {{3,4,5}}} *)
```

Comment: This is cool, but could you add a little explanation of what your code does for the benefit of less experienced future visitors?